# Pass external parameter to Custom View

Tags: android, android-animation, subclass, android-custom-view

I just get going on drawing, canvas, basic animations but have stumbled upon this annoying issue:

I have a CustomView

```
public class CustomView extends View{
   //

   //Edited code ****************************
   bool dir;    // true -- right-to-left, false -- left-to-right

   public void setDirection(bool b)
       this.bool = b 

   // ****************************************


   public CustomView(Context context) {
     super(context);
     ...
   }
   public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs)
    ...
   }
   ...

   //stuff for animation
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
   ...
  }
  ...
```

and inside I have created a little animation, basically something flying **from right to left** over and over again.

Now, let's say I wanted to have 2 of these views in my layout. But on the second one, stuff should fly **from  left to right**.

Is it possible to somehow pass this "parameter" to the Custom view? or do I really have to create the exact same class and change a plus sign to a minus sign and make it thereby a new class. This would mean animations created by extending view are not tunable at all.

If the latter is the case, then is there a better way to have tunable animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow pass this "parameter" to the Custom view?

Step #1: Add a field to your custom view to hold your animation

Step #2: Add a setter method to populate the field

Step #3: Call that setter method from something (activity, fragment, etc.) to tell it what animation to use

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Could you take a quick look at my edited code and tell me if this is want you meant?

Comment: @Marsl: That is a field and a setter method for the field. So long as you call `setDirection()` to teach a given `CustomView` which direction to use, and so long as you use `dir` inside `CustomView` to control its behavior, you should have what you are seeking.